What are these metal straps attached to exterior wall


I’m trying to repair some siding on my house (circa 1996). I got the siding off, and see that the plywood is in bad shape as well. My plan was to cut off the plywood and replace it, but these metal straps (roughly every 4 feet) are in my way.

What are they?
Can I cut them off, or are they still serving a purpose?
If I can’t cut them off, how far up the wall are they likely to go/how can I get around them?

Inside of the wall is nominally finished. The second photo shows the concrete pad (where water splashed onto the wall, damaging the siding), with the foundation barely showing (mossy green). I don’t need/want to remove more siding; it’s only the bottom few panels that were damaged.
Bonus question: why are there holes cut in the plywood? Inside the hole is just insulation, and then drywall on the other side. No wires, pipes, or anything else someone would need access to. Siding was directly over that…

looks like hurricane strapping to me.

Those are tie down straps.  You are probably in a location that requires tie down  strapping per code.
You should not remove them.  The best solution is to remove the siding until all of the strap is exposed.  ( Usually they are 18 to 24 inches.) however they could be longer.  Pull all the nails and move the straps back to replace the OSB. It looks like you should pull another course of siding anyway.
An option is contacting the local building department and asking what the code is for the minimum length for the strapping.  If you have more than that going up the wall, you could cut the existing to at least the minimum.
You cannot remove them.  They keep your house anchored in strong winds.
